# marshalling arbitrary-length binary data from udp() object

Tags: matlab, networking

I am reading binary data from instrumentation using the Matlab udp() object.

I am surprised by the apparent lack of support for reading arbitrary length data types. How does one read a 24-bit integer? Or a 24-bit float? These are not that strange in instrumentation, and I have found only 8/16/32/64 data types in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked tried `help fread`?  The documentation shows it supports reading up to 64 bits at a time using `bitN` where N is a value between 1 and 64.

```
fid = udp(<your parameters here>);  % use fopen to open the stream.
...
A = fread(fid,1,'bit24=>int32');  % stream 24 bits to a 32 bit integer.
B = fread(fid,1,'ubit24=>uint32');  % stream 24 bits to a 32 bit unsigned integer.
```

Since floating point specs vary, so this may or may not work for your situation:

```
C = fread(fid,1,'bit24=>float32');  % transcode 24bits to 32 bit float (MATLAB spec)
```

**UPDATE**

Seeing that the `udp/fread` implementation does not support this casting there are a couple, not-so-pretty, workarounds you can try.

1. Read in `uchar` data in multiples of three and then multiply it by their byte offsets directly.  For example:

   ```
   % First determine number of bytes on the stream and make sure you
   % have at 3 or more bytes to read so you can calculate thirdOfBytesExpected.  

   [anMx3result, packetCount] = fread(fid,[thirdOfBytesExpected,3]);
   unsigned20bitInt = anMx3result*(2.^(0:8:16))';
   ```

   To be precise, the unsigned20bitInt is actually stored as a MATLAB `double` here.  So if you need to write it elsewhere, you will need to bring it back to the individual `uchar` types it came from.
2. The not so pretty option is to eat the overhead of streaming the data back to a binary file format as an interim step so that you can then use the base `fread` method mentioned above.  Not an ideal solution, but perhaps worth considering if you just need *something* to work.

   ```
   % your original code for opening the udp handle

    ....

   tmpFid = fopen('tmp.bin','rw');
   [ucharVec, bytesRead] = fread(udpFid,bytesExpected,'uchar=>uchar');
   bytesWritten = fwrite(tmpFid,ucharVec,'uchar');

   % Do some quality control on bytes read vs written ...

   fseek(tmpFid,-bytesWritten,'cof');  
   % in theory you should be able to just go to the beginning 
   % of the file each time like this fseek(tmpFid, 0, 'bof');
   % provided you also reset to the beginning prior writing or after reading

   % Read in the data as described originally
   num24ByteIntsToRead = bytesWritten/3;
   A = fread(tmpFid,num24BytsIntsToRead,'bit24=>int32');
   ```

Comment: I expected the behavior you describe, and wrote code planning to use it, but I see different implementations of file/fread() and udp/fread(), with the latter not supporting the => casting statements. Am I am getting lost in overloading, and should I be getting another fread function instead?

Comment: It may or may not make a difference, but which version of MATLAB are you using?  I'll take another look.

Comment: I am using R2016b. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you will have to go with one of the updated options then; perhaps try number 1 first.  Let me know if it works or if you come up with something else instead.  I know its a chore to write bit level stuff, so if you find an easier way, please share :)

Comment: I read uint8 (bytes) individually and then used bitshift() before adding them together. It is really a shame the Mathworks does not keep the same fread implementation across file and network objects... that should be the whole point of network sockets being presented as file abstractions!

Comment: Agreed.  Ah well.  That's right, I forgot about bitshift.  I think it is the same as the same as the multiplication by 2^(number of bits) but a lot cleaner than writing `2.^(0:8:16))'` ;).  Good reminder, thanks!